# Is there a shell which supports fuzzy completion as in Sublime Text?

Tags: bash, shell, tab-completion

I'm using bash and I was wondering if there is any plugin in bash or other shell which allows me to do this
`cat tfnislong.txt` + `[tab]` completes to `cat ThisFileNameIsSoLong.txt` just like tab completion in Sublime Text.

Comment: Why not just do `cat Th` + `tab`?

Comment: @daviewales Display all 269 reasons?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know of https://github.com/mgalgs/fuzzy_bash_completion which is a bunch of shell functions used with `complete`.

I think we could probably do a little better though, be more concise. Time to bust open your .bashrc or .profile...

The basic hook we use is this:

`complete -o nospace -o filenames -F fuzzypath cd ls cat`

-F option means use a shell function for the tab-completion, where the options are set in the `COMPREPLY` variable. So for example:

```
function fuzzypath() {
    if [ -z $2 ] 
    then
        COMPREPLY=( `ls` )
    else
        DIRPATH=`echo "$2" | gsed 's|[^/]*$||'`
        BASENAME=`echo "$2" | gsed 's|.*/||'`
        FILTER=`echo "$BASENAME" | gsed 's|.|\0.*|g'`
        COMPREPLY=( `ls $DIRPATH | grep -i "$FILTER" | gsed "s|^|$DIRPATH|g"` )
    fi
}
```

where `DIRPATH` is everything before the last / on your path that you're typing and `BASENAME` is where your cursor is currently.

`FILTER` is where the fuzzy-ness comes in. Basically, take `BASENAME` and insert a `.*` between every char to produce our fuzz regex.

The rest is just combining the regex with ls to produce `COMPREPLY`. You may find more clever things to do here, maybe with `find`.

I also found http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com/2011/04/writing-your-own-bash-completion.html to be useful.

Comment: This approach has the same problem I encountered in a short version I wrote: if you hit tab and there are multiple matching results, they are listed as expected (which is good). But then the fuzzy search string you've typed so far will be replaced by the common prefix of the matching results (which can be bad because it takes your search process back to square one if that common prefix is also shared by other items not in the matching results).

Answer (score 7):

You may find [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) useful. It's a general purpose fuzzy finder written in Ruby that can be used with any list of things: files, processes, command history, git branches, etc.

Its install script will setup `CTRL-T` keybinding for your shell. The following GIF shows how it works.

[image]

Comment: FZF is great! Thanks a lot for contributing. This saved me weeks of work..I was starting to write fuzzy completion for Bash when I luckily found FZF. It works perfect, I just had to remember to save cursor position before calling `fzf` .. (tput sc) and later restore it with `tput rc`..

Answer (score 3):

To go along with your other answer, you might want to look into zsh.  It's backwards compatible with bash so you can use it as a drop in replacement, but it supports significantly expanded features and one of them is greatly enhanced context aware tab completion.

[zsh Completion FAQ](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq04.html) expands on the use cases, but I do believe that per your example, you would be most interested in the `COMPLETE_IN_WORD`function.  It is not quite the desired behavior, but it's close.  The main point is that there are a lot of ways to extend upon the base functionality in a maybe more approachable way than using bash.

Here is a fuzzy match extension that would approximate what you want more specifically;  [zsh-fuzzy match](https://github.com/tarruda/zsh-fuzzy-match%20zsh-fuzzy-match)

For some ideas you could take a look at the popular [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) framework that has a number of functions for managing zsh and extending it.  It's more than you want, most likely, but under the plugins you'll note auto-completion scripts for a variety of roles.  To get an idea of the capabilities.